# How to add sub folders in Mailer templates in Nest Js

Tags: typescript, email, nestjs

I'm quite new in Nest JS and I'm trying to send mails and I did all configuration described to @nestjs-modules/mailer, [Here](https://nest-modules.github.io/mailer/docs/mailer.html). My configuration in app.module:

```
 MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: process.env.SENDIN_BLUE_TRANSPORTER,
      defaults: {
        from:`"${process.env.SENDIN_BLUE_SENDER_NAME}" <${process.env.SENDIN_BLUE_SENDER_MAIL}>`,
      },
      template: {
        dir: __dirname + '/templates',
        adapter: new PugAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
    }),
```

My folder structure in src:

```
.
+--user
|  +--auth
|  +--controller
|  +--service
|  |  +--user.service.ts
|  +--user.module.ts
+--templates
|  +--user
|  |  +--confirm-email.pug
|  +--email
|  |  +--base-email.pug
+--app.module.ts
```

I injected the MailerService and send email in this way:

```
const mail = await this.mailService
      .sendMail({
        to: customerPerson.per_mail,
        subject: 'Subject',
        template: 'user/confirm-mail',
        context: {
          user_name: customerPerson.per_name + ' ' + customerPerson.per_lastname,
          user_mail: customerPerson.per_mail,
          url_confirm_pass: tokenMail
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {console.log("Email:response:" , res)})
      .catch((err) => {console.log("Email:error:" , err)});
```

But then in the console I get this:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'user\confirm-mail.pug'
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code or if I'm missing something. I had to copy the template folder to dist because is not copied in compilation.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `__dirname`, it will return current working directory in dist, and when running, nest doesn't copy `.pug` file to `dist`.

Move your template folder out of `src` folder and try again

Answer (score 0):

This module doesn't work that way. To do it, you need to pass absolute path in your sendMail method like that:

```
const mail = await this.mailService
      .sendMail({
        to: customerPerson.per_mail,
        subject: 'Subject',
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'templates', 'user', 'confirm-mail'),
        context: {
          user_name: customerPerson.per_name + ' ' + customerPerson.per_lastname,
          user_mail: customerPerson.per_mail,
          url_confirm_pass: tokenMail
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {console.log("Email:response:" , res)})
      .catch((err) => {console.log("Email:error:" , err)});
```

It's should work after build too.

Maybe I will make one pull request in this project with implementation to use 'subfolder/template' in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement of @Petrus de Melo anwswer.

Add this in the `mail.module.ts`

```
import { join } from 'path';

export const MAIL_TEMPLATES_PATH = join(__dirname, 'templates/');

// a helper function which generates the full path to the mail template
export const getFullTemplatePath = (templatePath: string): string => {
    return path.resolve(MAIL_TEMPLATES_PATH, ...templatePath.split("/"))
}
```

Then replace the template option in `sendMail` like this:

```
const mail = await this.mailService.sendMail({
      ....
      template: getFullTemplatePath('user/confirm-mail'),
      ....
   })
```